# Identify the xpath to select dropdown in phptravels.net site

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I need help to identify the `xpath` for entering text and select from a dropdown (in `https://www.phptravels.net`) using Robot framework.

- Click on Hotels option
- enter text like 'Delhi
- enter text like 'Delhi' and select from dropdown the city 'Delhi

Using Robot framework and selenium library.

```
    Input Text  xpath://*[@id=\"select2-drop\"]                             Delhi,India 
    Input Text  xpath://*[@id=\"select2-drop\"]/div/input                   Delhi,India 
    Input Text  xpath://*[contains(text(),'Search by Hotel or City Name')]  Delhi
```

I get following error:

> Element with locator not found

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a hint for the next time: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In the case of xpath: `[contains(text(),'your_text')]` should work.

Try this:

```
click element   xpath=//*[@id="s2id_location"]/a/span[1]
input text    xpath=//*[@id="select2-drop"]/div/input  Delhi
wait until page contains element  xpath=//li[2]/div/span[contains(text(),'Delhi')]
click element  xpath=//li[2]/div/span[contains(text(),'Delhi')]
page should contain element  xpath=//a/span[1][contains(text(),'Delhi, India')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Click element try `Press Keys <locator> //13`. That would work.

Comment: Before you Input a text, you should first click the textarea as suggested by Konstatin V